# How to read Ansible log

Tags: ansible

Is there any way to read the Ansible log file as a JSON or YAML, or would I have to write my own parser?

The Ansible log file looks like this:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have [different plugins](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.5/plugins/callback.html#plugin-list) that can help you modify the output, for example, if you just want it to be in json check https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.5/plugins/callback/json.html.

For this to work, you need to add and `stdout_callback` in your `ansible.cf`, for example:

```
[defaults]
stdout_callback = json
callback_whitelist = json, timer
...
```

For more details check the [Managing stdout](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.5/plugins/callback.html#managing-stdout) section in the docs.

Answer (score -1):

Ansible uses json extensively in internal to manage data, hence uses this format to display information, but you have several [callback plugins](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.5/plugins/callback.html) to change the way errors and messages are displayed on screen.

Comment: After Installing a playbook, I can't get data as a json ? 
I cant change the way that the error messages are display.